# MathJax Проблема с inline и display

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mathjax

Стоит вот такая конфигурация для MathJax:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
 MathJax.Hub.Config({
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
  processEscapes: true,
  balanceBraces:true
},
"HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
 });
</script>
```

Но в выводе все равно выводит \[ и \]. Что делать?

[image]

**Обновление**

Рендерится последней строкой, а вывод делается самим mathjax с помощью script

```
str= $('#testbox').attr('value').toString();// testbox - input type = text 

$('#latex').children('script').remove();
$('#latex').children("span").remove();
$('#latex').append($('<script type="math/tex" >').text(str));


MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Выводит в чём? Как делается рендеринг?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я хочу, чтобы в выводе не было \\[ и \\]